# View/Layout inside RelativeLayout not visible in PreLollipop devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

`Views`/`RelativeLayout` are not visible on pre-`Lollipop` devices. I also tried with color resource instead of drawable resources. Earlier I tried with `View` inside the `RelativeLayout`, but didn't work. Inside `View`/`Layout` have hardcoded width 5`dp`.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/side_line1"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/subject_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/subject_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_8_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_round_corner_orange"
    android:id="@+id/side_line_1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    ></RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_8_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_round_corner_orange"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/side_line_1_colored"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    ></RelativeLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/step_one"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    layout="@layout/layout_step"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="5dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_8_dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_round_corner_orange"
android:id="@+id/side_line_1"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
></RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="5dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_8_dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_round_corner_orange"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/side_line_1_colored"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
></RelativeLayout>
```

To

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="5dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_8_dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_round_corner_orange"
android:id="@+id/side_line_1"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="5dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/pad_8_dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_round_corner_orange"
android:visibility="gone"
android:id="@+id/side_line_1_colored"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>
```

This should work fine.

Comment: can you tell me the difference you made

Comment: I change the `<RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>` to `<RelativeLayout/>` because maybe is loading that need to have something inside the `RelativeLayout` and because that it doesn't do it what you want.